# How can I find out what region code a DVD is in on my Windows PC?

Tags: windows, dvd

How can I find out what region code a DVD is in on my Windows PC?  I use AnyDVD so the DVD plays regardless, so I'm not sure whether the region code on the DVD packaging is correct or whether it is actually regionless.  Is there any way to check this?

Edit: Just to make it clearer, I'm looking for **the region code of the DVD, not the DVD drive**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WinDVD](http://windvd.en.softonic.com/) will tell you this under "Configuration".

[DVD Info Pro](http://www.dvdinfopro.com/) will also do this - despite it looking like it costs, on the left side of their site you can get it for free.

[DVD Identifier](http://www.afterdawn.com/software/cd_dvd/dvd_tools/dvd_identifier.cfm) is also free and will provide this information.

---

As an aside, if you need to change your machine to read a certain region follow instructions below.

Control Panel -> System. On the left side, click on Device Manager.

In the new Window, typically under DVD/CD-ROM drives right click on your DVD/CD drive and select properties.

The second tab is called DVD Region. You are also normally limited to the number of times you can change it (in the picture below it shows Changes remaining: 5) even if you re-install Windows.

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for the region code of the _DVD_.  Not the _DVD drive_.

Comment: @dlanod: Don't get hung up on the explanation of how to change the region code (which takes up most of the answer).  Just read the top part again.

Comment: Out of the top part, only DVD Identifier looks like it's not referring to the drive so I'll give that a go, but given 95% refers to the drive funnily enough I didn't expect the actual information to be hidden behind a link. :)